# VBA Excel save txt as txt UTF-8

Tags: excel, vba

I got all of my code working, but this saves the txt in ANSI, would like to save txt as UTF-8, could some help me please with this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()
    
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Test"
    
    Dim FileName As String: FileName = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hh.mm ") & " Test"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName & ".txt", xlCSV, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the documentation for Workbook.SaveAs, especially the FileFormat argument.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: Thanks, I already checked this sadly nothing for txt as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple options to modify your `SaveAs`

Try any of these"

```
'My best guess that will work
dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName, xlCurrentPlatformText, Local:=True

'Alternative text
dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName, xlUnicodeText, Local:=True

'CSV approach
dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName, xlCSVUTF8, Local:=True
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this!

Comment: I have to check this again, xlCSVUTF8, returns to an error.

Comment: It would be related to the file. Not the code. Pretty standard routine.

Comment: Im going to check this today!

Comment: It seems that xlCSVUTF8 works but it saves as UTF-8 with BOM, is there anyway to save this without the BOM part?

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble, however you get what you pay for on StackOverflow, and your question was how to save as a `UTF-8`, which appears I answered based on your latest comment. I can see it's not quite what you wanted, which is unfortunate however the proper thing to do would be to `accept` a correct answer to your question and then post a new question that is mor precise in trying to get the result you need. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @PGSystemTester! Will do that!